# How can I get the value of k?

Tags: gamma-function, polygamma

I have to get the value of k in this equation: $\frac{(\lambda T)^k [ln(\lambda T)-\psi(k+1)]}{\Gamma(k+1)}=0$, where $\psi$ is the digamma function. Since $\Gamma(k+1)$ is in the denominator and the value for k would be $-\infty$ for $(\lambda T)^k$ I am trying to solve this: $ln(\lambda T)=\psi(k+1)$. I've tried to solve replace $\psi(k+1)$ by its intregral representation: [image]

But I haven´t been able to get an answer.

Comment: Do you expect a closed form ?

Comment: Yes, because I am trying to find the k that maximizes that equation. I nee to get an expresion in terms of T and $\lambda$

Comment: Which equation ? Is what you wrote its derivative ? We can have an approximate solution (if $\lambda T$ is sufficiently large).

Comment: The equation that I derivate was $\frac{(\lambda T)^k exp\{-\lambda T\}}{k!}$ and I got this from a stopping game problem, a poisson process witg rate $\lambda$. Each time an event occurs we must decide whether or not to stop, with our objective being to stop at the last event to occur prior to some specified time T. Hence P(win)=P(N(T)=k)=$\frac{(\lambda T)^k exp\{-\lambda T\}}{k!}$

Comment: Do you care for an approximate solution ? What is the order of magnitude of $\lambda T$ ?

Comment: Both of them $\epsilon (0,\infty)$